# What is the difference between Concatenate() and concatenate() layers in Keras / TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow 2.0, whose layer functions are based on Keras. What is the difference between the `Concatenate()` and `concatenate()` layers?

Answer (score 5):

Keras provides 2 kinds of API i.e. Sequential and Functional. And because of this 2 kind of API, the difference is there in them.

- Concatenate is used when you are using Sequential API
- concatenate is used when you are using Functional API

Just look into the following documentation:
https://keras.io/layers/merge/

Answer (score 2):

Keras has two basic organizational modes: "Sequential" and "Functional".  `concatenate` is the functional version, and really just wraps the `Concatenate` layer.

from source: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merge.py#L638

```
def concatenate(inputs, axis=-1, **kwargs):
    """...snip documentation..."""
    return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
```